# Type value plusHours is not a member of org.joda.time.DateTime

Tags: scala, datetime, jodatime

I'm using Scala and Joda time, but I can't use most methods.

For example this works fine

```
var now = DateTime.now()
```

But this doesn't

```
var now = DateTime.now()
var then = now.plusHours(2)
```

**Type value plusHours is not a member of org.joda.time.DateTime**

If i build i receive also these errors:

error while loading DateTime, Missing dependency 'class org.joda.convert.FromString', required by C:\Documents and Settings\Vallo\Mis documentos\Downloads\joda-time-2.2.jar(org/joda/time/DateTime.class)  TP4     Unknown Scala Problem

error while loading DateTimeZone, Missing dependency 'class org.joda.convert.FromString', required by C:\Documents and Settings\Vallo\Mis documentos\Downloads\joda-time-2.2.jar(org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.class)  TP4     Unknown Scala Problem

error while loading AbstractInstant, Missing dependency 'class org.joda.convert.ToString', required by C:\Documents and Settings\Vallo\Mis documentos\Downloads\joda-time-2.2.jar(org/joda/time/base/AbstractInstant.class) TP4     Unknown Scala Problem

(the file C:\Documents and Settings\Vallo\Mis documentos\Downloads\joda-time-2.2.jar exists)

However, methods like DateTime.isBefore or .isAfter works fine. I've got the feeling that static methods are the only one that work for me, but I'm not sure.

Any clues? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you might need to add [joda-convert](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3a%22org.joda%22%20AND%20a%3a%22joda-convert%22) as a dependency too.

Comment: @Vallo please tick this one as the accepted answer if it helped you solve your problem